# Tremolo strokes above stems with flags

Tags: notation, sheet-music, engraving, tremolo

Is it okay to draw tremolo strokes above/below stems with flags for more readability? Otherwise, it looks a bit tight when tremolo strokes are positioned right on a stem with a flag:

[image: example of tremolo beams above/below notes with flags]

Also, I just don't want to increase the stem height, because it would look even worse in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel that it is necessary you can do anything, as long as you make sure it is clear what you want. When you introduce non standard notation you need to be sure to explain it well, and usually in places where there is a standard notation, you should think at least thrice before going for a custom notation. You need to consider carefully if in your particular case (that is the notated material as well as the intended audience and performance situation) whether the benefit you assume from you notation is worth abandoning standard notation for.

Now if we compare these examples:

[image: example of standard tremolo notation (tremolo beams between note head and flag), and proposed notation (tremolo beams beyond flag)]

I cannot think of many examples where the latter would really outperform the first. But, some cases where this *could* make sense would be:

1. Scores for visually impaired people.
2. Scores for small children (but these tend not to feature tremolo).
3. Scores that are so complex that they require you to shorten the stems so much you do not have space for tremolo. But here the solution would probably not be adding them on top, because then you could simply use longer stems.
4. Scores where equal stem length between tremolo notes and non tremolo notes are important for optical reasons.
5. Really **really** small study scores. If you do a score at rastral height 10pt for example, this might just be too small to read the tremolo if notated conventionally:

[image: example as above but with rastral height 10pt (very small) - tremolo beams are hard resolve]

In most cases though, I do not see the need to do so. If you really feel convinced that your reason is good enough, feel free to do it, but make sure to clarify the meaning. Notation is always flexible, there are not so much "rules" than conventions and good practices. Many challenging scores have led to creative solutions in notating them. But try to adhere to conventions as much as possible, unless there is a really convincing reason to do otherwise.

Musicians are trained to read conventions. If you do your own thing you’ll confuse them. This will mean more time is needed to be spent rehearsing (because the musicians will need not only to learn the piece but also the notation) and will as a direct consequence reduce the chance that anyone will even consider performing the score (unless you are a really big name composer, at this point you will be able to throw anything at musicians and it will be performed. But if a normal composer hands in a score to an orchestra or an ensemble and tells them that they need to learn special notation — chances are high they are not even going to look at the score and will play something else).

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. I can notice that in first image tremolo strokes are bit shorter horizontally, is it default behaviour of the software you're using?

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov Yes, Lilypond shortens stem tremolo beams on flagged notes with stem going up to avoid collision between tremolo beams and the flag.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not standard notation.  If it takes a longer stem, write a longer stem.

Comment: do you have any reference where it's claimed that it's the only way to place tremolo strokes?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative.  I think YOU'VE got to find a reference claiming that it IS :-)

Comment: I guess, you're right